# Make Teams notify a custom API on a new project/team being created

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-teams

I'd like to get a call to my API from Teams when a new project is created. Something like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744123/creating-a-new-team-project-using-the-rest-api) but the other way around.

When a user creates a new project in Teams, I need to get notified about that and learn the ID of the creator and the project itself, possibly with some extra parameters.

When I google that issue, I only get info on the notifications in the GUI and questions on how to programmatically create the project from the custom application. I'm new to how Teams work and may be missing something obvious, though. What terms should I aim for to get more info? I've seen [some suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64800895/1525840) on relying on a bot but I wish my integration to be automatic, not relying on user input (other than creating the new project/team).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to have Teams tell you this, you might need to go the other way around and poll the Graph API periodically. There is an operation to [return all Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0), but be sure to request the Created Date and match it against your polling interval.

Comment: Does the same hold for additions of users to a team? And, consequently, removals?

Comment: I've been looking more and there's a notification resource that I think will indeed give you new Team creation, as well as all the other things (users, channels etc.). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-change-notification-in-microsoft-teams-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: It's waaay too late for my brains now. But tomorrow, I'll poke around at the links you provided. I checked a quicky just now and I see mentions suggesting that it's possible to subscribe to the changes, hence react to them as they occur. The best would be a how-to-guide and I hope there's something like that among the links. Thanks.